# How can I access the scheduled tasks of a windows 2003 server from a windows 7 machine on a different domain?

Tags: windows, task-scheduler

I have looked everywhere for information but have not managed to find a solution.

What I need to do is be able to access the Scheduled Tasks of a Windows 2003 Server that is in domain X from a Windows 7 machine in domain Y.

If I run \\win2003server from the windows 7 machine I can access it and see the shared folders, but I cannot see the Scheduled Tasks.

I have tried to add a snap-in via MMC of type Task Scheduler pointing to another computer, but I get the error "Task Scheduler service is not available. Verify that the service is running." I know it is running.

From another machine (not windows 7) in the same domain as the win2003 server I can see the Sheduled Tasks folder by running \\win2003server

I am not sure whether the problem is down to Windows 7 or the domain and I do not know whether I have to change policies or permissions or something else.

Please can somebody help?

Thank you and best regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

i'm not sure but i think it's not supported do use the Windows 7 Task Scheduler Manager to manage Windows 2003 Tasks. But you can use the cli tool schtasks. In a test from my Windows 7 machine i run a Task query for a remote Windows 2003 Server (different Domain) and it works fine.

```
C:\>schtasks /query /S 10.1.1.114

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
ACSMailReport                            06.02.2013 01:00:00    Ready
MP Scheduled Quick Scan                  Disabled               Unknown
MP Scheduled Scan                        06.02.2013 02:27:00    Ready
MP Scheduled Signature Update            Disabled               Unknown
ACS_Logons_2SQL                          06.02.2013 00:30:00    Ready
ACS_Logons_GetFileName                   05.02.2013 23:30:00    Ready
```

i have mapped a network drive from this server so i don't need /u and /p for username and password.

Here are some Docs for you:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!  What I am trying to is access and run a Scheduled Task that has been defined on a Win 2003 server from a Windows 7 machine.  Since this task will be run manually from remote (not scheduled for a certain time), I need to be able to view and schedule it.  I'm not sure whether this would be considered as "managing" the task... I'd also like to add that whenever I used the CLI I seem to get the error "ERROR: The remote procedure call failed."  Is there a particular setting that I have to set on the server?

Comment: Could you post me the syntax of the successful query?

Comment: i edited my answer with the successful query. for running a task just use the /run option.

"ERROR: The remote procedure call failed." may be a result of the Server 2003 Firewall Settings. Can you check the FW setting.

Comment: thanks for the update.  I checked and the firewall is disabled.  Do you know what else could be obstructing the call?

Comment: the Task Scheduler Service on 2003 Server must be in running state. Maybe it is an Authentication Problem. Try to map a network share from the 2003 Server and run the command again. if your Problems further exist there would be another solution for you. you can configure the 2003 Server as an Telnet Server. Then you can telnet from your Windows 7 to the Server and run the schtasks command on the 2003 Server.

Comment: The thing that made it is **I mapped a network drive from the server so I don't need /u and /p...**.  This is key.  From a Server 2008+ machine, if you set the u/p params, it still doesn't work.  But mapping the drive and "pre-authenticating" the request allows you to query the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with SCHTASKS from Win7 machine to execute JOB at W2K3 machine:

```
C:\Users\MrCMD>SCHTASKS.exe /Run /S \\Remote-Machine /U DOMAIN\admin /P master-cmd /TN "MSL4048 Tape Backup Scan (Tue to Fri)"
ERROR: The request is not supported.

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Fri 06/28/2013 13:15:36.44 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
C:\Users\MrCMD>SCHTASKS.exe /Run /S \\Remote-Machine /TN "MSL4048 Tape Backup Scan (Tue to Fri)"
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "MSL4048 Tape Backup Scan (Tue to Fri)".

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Fri 06/28/2013 13:15:46.33 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
C:\Users\MrCMD>SCHTASKS.exe /QUERY /FO TABLE /S \\Remote-Machine

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
MSL4048 Tape Backup Scan (Mon)           7/1/2013 12:20:00 PM   Ready
MSL4048 Tape Backup Scan (Tue to Fri)    6/28/2013 2:20:00 PM   Ready
reboot                                   N/A                    Ready
ReName AUTORUN INF and DESKTOP INI       Disabled               Unknown

┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Executed Fri 06/28/2013 13:17:55.77 │ As [MrCMD]
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Fortune or not, it's happened after I read this thread. :)